# Maven jandex plugin does not generate index for local custom maven repositories (sometimes)

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, quarkus, jandex

I have a multi module maven project wie quarkus modules and some custom libraries which are local maven repositories (so they can be used by the other maven projects/modules). However, so that local maven repositories are recognizable und usable by your other local maven projects, you have to manually index them for some reason. I.e. add a config like this for quarkus index to the application.properties of the project including the local maven repo dependency:

```
quarkus.index-dependency.<index-name>.group-id = <group-id-of-local-maven-repo>
quarkus.index-dependency.<index-name>.artifact-id = <artifact-id-of-local-maven-repo>
```

The problem is, this causes issues for me becausse if you have 3 layers of project dependencies, say:

1. **Project A** (custom local maven repo library)
2. **Project B** (custom local maven repo library, includes Project A dependency)

   - *application.properties* (indexing Project A library dependency)
3. **Project C** (Local maven project for an end product, includes Project B
   library dependency - and through it indirectly Project A).

   - *application.properties* (indexing Project B library dependency and config for datasources or other app related things)

Then when you generate an **uber-jar** (fat jar) of Project C for deployment, it for some reason uses *application.properties* of Project B in the packaged jar, instead of from the project which im building (Project C). Thus, the app is missing key configs and does not work. Maven seems to use an inverse priority here, which i dont know if thats a bug or not. When i asked about this, i was simply told that:

"My dependencies should not have *application.properties*".

I tried to find a way to prevent manual indexing via *application.properties* and found the **maven jandex plugin** - which is supposed to generate an index. The next problem is, this seems to only work in some projects but not in others in the dependency hierarchy, resulting in the same situation as before, and i don't understand why. This is the pom.xml config for the plugin i have included in all 3 projects (the entire pom.xml for all is too long, so let me know if you need more info):

```
<properties>
    ...
    <jandex.skip>false</jandex.skip>
    ...
</properties>
...
<build>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>3.0.5</version>     
        <inherited>true</inherited> 
        <executions>
           <execution>  
              <id>make-index</id>
              <goals>
                 <goal>jandex</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <skip>${jandex.skip}</skip>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
```

The odd thing is, this works to the extend that i no longer have to index Project B library dependency in Project C *application.properties*, but Project B library dependency still has to manually index Project A library dependency - thus rendering the entire exercise futile. Project C having an *application.properties* was never the issue, and is obviously needed. Project B still requires a properties file to point to Project A now, **how do i solve this?**

---

I have a parent module POM in the root folder containing all these projects, over which this maven jandex dependency is distributed to all modules, so it looks like this:

- Maven parent module (contains all dependencies and versions used by all project sub modules)

  1. **Project A** (custom local maven library repo), own pom.xml with inheritance from parent module
  2. **Project B** (custom local maven library repo, includes Project A library), own pom.xml with inheritance from parent module

     - *application.properties* - Indexes Project A dependency manually, **this is the problematic one which needs to go!**
  3. **Project C** (Local maven project for REST API etc., includes Project B library), own pom.xml with inheritance from parent module

  pom.xml (parent module POM, containing maven jandex dependepency among others)

---

Edit: One of the projects, "entity", where all the database access objects are stored, does not run the jandex plugin during `mvn clean install`. This is the POM of the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.compamny.project</groupId>
   <artifactId>entity</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.smallrye/jandex-maven-plugin -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   <build>
     <pluginManagement>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.0</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.2</version>
         </plugin>
       <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
         <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>        
         <inherited>true</inherited>
         <executions>
           <execution>            
             <id>make-index</id>
             <goals>
                <goal>jandex</goal>
             </goals>
           </execution>
         </executions>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
 </build>
</project>
```

When i force the execution of the jandex goal with `mvn io.smallrye:jandex-maven-plugin:3.0.0:jandex` it creates an META-INF/jandex.jdx file, but it does not produce one when i run `mvn clean install`. This is not a solution since i need to build the project, run the jandex plugin and install it into my local repositories separately. Also, notice that im using the "io.smallrye" version of the jandex plugin since the "org.jboss" version seems to not work at all.

Comment: Do you have a log of the Maven build? Can you confirm from the log that the `jandex-maven-plugin` runs in _all 3_ projects?

Comment: @Ladicek Yes, the jandex maven plugin pops up in the console log when im building the projects either all from the parent POM or individually. Its says its running the "jandex" goal and generated a .idx file apparently in every project.

Comment: OK, so all the JARs have a `META-INF/jandex.idx` file in them, right? Then it should just work and the problem is likely elsewhere...

Comment: @Ladicek Sorry for the late response! I really need some help with this. I noticed that in one project which gets included jandex does not pop up in the console when building it, although the jandex plugin is set in the build config POM of the project. It works if i manually force the execution of the "jandex" goal in the command line, but then i need to do compilation, jandex and install in separate steps lol.

Comment: @Ladicek I will post the POM.xml of the project where the jandex plugin does not run automatically although it is configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The jandex plugin was set in the `<pluginManagement>` section of the POM configuration, which made it not run on `mvn clean install`. I had to move it to the `plugins` section so it gets executed. Thanks @Ladicek for making me look closer and keep trying!

Comment: Damn! Being in a hurry i misplaced my plugin section as well

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for.